# using JQuery fileTree for Apache Cordova application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, apache-cordova

I am trying to use this File Tree For my Apache Cordova Application.

As it cannot contain any server side scripts, the script must be placed into a seperate project and be called from the client side (apache cordova app).

So that means I need to call the script with Ajax jquery and display the files.

How do I do it using [**this JqueryFile browser JQuery fileTree**](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/#download)?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 approaches.

1) Use Cordova File api to get a list of directories/files to render a file tree in your JS application(i.e. Populate jQuery file tree)
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryReader

2) I have not used this plugin myself, but you can use a Cordova plugin like below to access the native file system:

[Cordova Plugin File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

You can not run a JavaScript library on the native side, you'd need to write code in ObjectiveC/Swift for iOS or Java for Android and create a plugin like above.